# Do granite tiles emit radioactive radon gas?

Tags: environmental-health, radiation

I have read that granite tiles emit radioactive radon gas, which is a health hazard.

Is this true?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/radiation/ -- compare the entries for "living in a stone building for a year" and "normal yearly background dose"

Comment: Just confirming that this is a notable claim, based on a Google search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EPA article, [Radiation Protection - Granite Countertops and Radiation](http://www.epa.gov/radiation/tenorm/granite-countertops.html) confirms that granite tiles do in fact emit radon gas:

> Any type of rock could contain naturally occurring radioactive
>   elements like radium, uranium and thorium. Some pieces of granite
>   contain more of these elements than others, depending on the
>   composition of the molten rock from which they formed. If present,
>   these radioactive elements will decay into radon, a colorless,
>   odorless, radioactive gas which may be released from the granite over
>   time.

However, the amount of radon emitted by granite tiles (for example in countertops) is highly unlikely to be a health risk

> However, since granite is generally not very porous, less radon is
>   likely to escape from it than from a more porous stone such as
>   sandstone. It’s important to know that radon originating in the soil
>   beneath homes is a more common problem and a far larger public health
>   risk than radon from granite building materials. Also, any radon from
>   granite countertops in kitchens or bathrooms is likely to be diluted
>   in the typical home since those rooms are usually well ventilated.
>
> In addition to radon, the other natural radioactive material in the
>   granite can emit radiation. However, it is extremely unlikely that
>   granite countertops in homes could increase the radiation dose above
>   that the normal, natural background dose that comes from soil and
>   rocks.

Comment: If your house is *built* on granite and is poorly ventilated it could be a whole different problem. But this is very different from having small amounts of granite in the house.